# Specifying multiple Git remotes for git_repository in Bazel

Tags: bazel

Our Bazel project pulls code from a private Git repository hosted on GitHub.

In some environments (which happen to all be macOS), we want to use SSH authentication to access the repo. So for these environments we can specify `remote = git@github.com:orgname/reponame.git` in the `new_git_repository` rule.

In other environments (which happen to all be Linux), we want to use token authentication to access the repo over HTTPS. For these environments we can use `remote = https://github.com/orgname/reponame.git`.

How can I create a WORKSPACE file that works in both environments? I tried using a `select` call like this:

```
new_git_repository(
   ...
   remote = select({
       "@bazel_tools//src/conditions:linux": "https://github.com/orgname/reponame.git",
       "@bazel_tools//src/conditions:darwin": "git@github.com:orgname/reponame.git",
   }),
)
```

but I got the error

```
ERROR: An error occurred during the fetch of repository 'myrepo':
   got value of type 'select' for attribute 'remote' of new_git_repository rule 'myrepo'; select may not be used in repository rules
```

It would be nice if `new_git_repository` had a `remotes` option that took a list (similar to `http_archive`'s `urls` option), but it doesn't.

Comment: Where `myrepo` comes from?

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski it was omitted in the ... part; it should say name = "myrepo" but I cut it out for brevity.

Answer (score 2):

`select()` can be used with build rules (for configurable attributes), but not repository rules. I do not think there is an entirely trivial way to accomplish what you've described.

I would really try to unify the authentication method and how I address and access the repo(s) across hosts.

If that was for some reason not possible, you could define "both" dependencies:

```
new_git_repository(
   name = "some_repo_mac",
   remote = "git@github.com:orgname/reponame.git",
   ...
)

new_git_repository(
   name = "some_repo_linux",
   remote = "https://github.com/orgname/reponame.git",
   ...
)
```

And perform the `select` (resolution) at a later stage:

```
alias(
    name = "some_ext_lib",
    actual = select({
       "@bazel_tools//src/conditions:linux_x86_64": "@some_repo_linux//:lib",
       "@bazel_tools//src/conditions:darwin_x86_64": "@some_repo_mac//:lib",
    }),
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

It will pollute your dependency graph, but external dependencies not needed won't actually be retrieved.

You also need to alias actual targets (one for each), not bunches of targets which may be provided and accessed through an external depedency.

You can automate that process with a macro and a small custom rule to generate the `alias` based selector...

Or you can just go ahead and write a custom rule for git fetching tying it into [`repository_ctx.os`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/lib/repository_ctx.html#os). At least I am not immediately aware of another method to access information about hosts OS at this stage of the build.